# One Javascript Control Multiple Form Submission

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to build a page with multiple forms submitting different values to another php script "another-script.php" using Javascript as shown below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="simple-msg"></div>

        <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="another-script.php" method="POST">
        <input type=hidden name=a value='value1'>
        <input type="button"  id="simple-post" value="Run Code" />
        </form>

        <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="another-script.php" method="POST">
        <input type=hidden name=a value='value2'>
        <input type="button"  id="simple-post" value="Run Code" />
        </form>

        <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="another-script.php" method="POST">
        <input type=hidden name=a value='value3'>
        <input type="button"  id="simple-post" value="Run Code" />
        </form>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {

                $("#simple-post").click(function()
                {
                    $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
                    {
                        $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='/logo/progress_bar.gif'/>");
                        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
                        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url : formURL,
                            type: "POST",
                            data : postData,
                            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                            {
                                $("#simple-msg").html('<pre>'+data+'</pre>');
                            },
                        });
                        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
                        e.unbind();
                    });

                    $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The forms should be able to submit different values by themselves but when using Javascript to submit to a different script "another-script.php", only the first form works. Would you please kindly advise what I should do to make each form submitting their own values.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Considering there are 3 forms with the same id, you'll most likely have to iterate over each of them and submit in the loop.  Put a class on them and iterate over each one.

```var forms = $(".simple-post");```
```$.each(forms, function(form){ /* submit code here */});```

Comment: IDs need to be unique, the selector only returns the first one. Use a class instead.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't bind the `submit` handler inside the `click` handler. It should be bound at top level. There's no need for the click handler at all -- clicking on the submit button triggers the form's submit event.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I am new to Javascript. Would you please make corrections on my code so that I can understand about what you are referring to? Thank you.